# bash script that scp with regex

Tags: glob, scp

I need some help. I am writing a bash script on RHEL that will use scp to download files from a remote server to the local machine.  the way the script works is that you pass it the remote server the source directory and destination directory and the files.
It works when I say the files to get is tes*   it will grab all the files that start with tes.
I can't get it working when I pass regex to it

The code is below

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTTIME=`/usr/bin/date +%H:%M:%S`
HOME=/home/oracle
export HOME

if [ "$4" = "" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [source path] [destination path] [scp server] [file pattern]" >&2
    exit 1
fi
###
#sending to tmp log file
echo "----------------------" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "StartTime ${STARTTIME}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.$$
echo "Push Files to ${3}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "Filemask is ${4}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "Source Path is ${1}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "Dest Path is ${2}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "SCP Server is ${3}" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$
echo "---------------------" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.log.$$

#The code below works when I use the filemask as te*
script -q -c "scp oracle@${3}:${1}${4} ${2}" >> /tmp/GetFile.log.$$

FILEMASK=${4}
echo "-----------------------------------" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.$$
awk -v searchterm="${FILEMASK}" '$0 ~ searchterm {IGNORECASE=1 ; print $1 }'          /tmp/GetFile.log.$$ | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.$$
echo "------------------------------------" | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.$$

RETURN_MESSAGE=" - Transfer From server1: "
export RETURN_MESSAGE
echo $RETURN_MESSAGE | tee -a /tmp/GetFile.$$
```

when I run it this is what I get
./GetFile /home/oracle/ /tmp server1 ten*.*

the following files are retrived
tenant.7366  100%  145     7.2KB/s   00:00
tenant.7367  100%   47     2.2KB/s   00:00
tenant.7369  100%   47     2.4KB/s   00:00

Now I have change it a little bit to try and get it working with regex
I comment the line below
#script -q -c "scp oracle@${3}:${1}${4} ${2}" >> /tmp/GetFile.log.$$

#I use this line instead
scp "oracle@${3}:${1}${4}${2}" >> /tmp/GetFile.log.$$

I run it like this
./GetFilev3 /home/oracle/ /tmp/ server1 "[te]*"

But I get the following extra files
ef345
et123
tenant.7366
tenant.7367
tenant.7369
tentt1
tentt2

Not sure what I am doing wrong all I want are the files starting with te

Comment: Arrgh why is `/tmp/GetFile.log.$$` not in a variable despite having 12 occurences in your file but other parameters which are used once do get their own variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are performing is a bash glob, not a regular expresison. I believe that you are matching on files that start with either the `t` or the `e` when you run `[te]*`.

What you want to do is likely the following. I supsect you will need to escape the asterisk to prevent the glob from resolving when you invoke it.   `./GetFilev3 /home/oracle/ /tmp/ server1 "te\*"`

Comment: I will give it a go and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Note there is a difference between [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and [regular expression patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). You tagged [glob](/questions/tagged/glob), but ask about regular expressions (which, unlike globs, are supported by `awk`).

`[te]*` *regular expression* means "there is zero or more characters `t` or `e`", which matches *every* string (the string `"cola"` has five places with zero or more `t`/`e`!). It does *not* mean "the strings starts with characters `te`". To do that, the regex is `^te`.

A related problem you might have faced is, if you had any files matching `[te]*` *glob* in the current directory (i.e. files whose name starts with `t` or `e` — not `te`!), they will get expanded due to the lack of quoting in this line:

```
FILEMASK=${4}
```

The line should instead be

```
FILEMASK="${4}"
```

This will not make any difference when you change the parameter to `^te`, but it should still be fixed.

I also can't see what you are using as input to `awk`. As the code stands, it is standard input. If you want to filter the filenames present on the remote, you would need to fetch the list of files so you could filter it.